# 'self' has lost something when declare function(self) within another function(self)

Tags: python, multithreading, function, pycharm, self

Please observe the following code (python 3.6 on Win10, PyCharm), function `thread0(self)` successfully starts as a thread, but `thread1(self)` seems be different from how `thread0(self)`is setup. `self.thread0` is fine,  but `self.thread1` is not. The `self` in `self.thread1` doesn't have `thread1` in its class functions, but it has everything from `__init__()`. As matter of fact, in PyCharm, the argument `self` is not even highlighted in the line `def thread1(self):`. My understanding is that syntax like `foo(self)` will add foo() to be a member of the class pointed by `self`.

Since we are here, I can not explain why the code in try-catch block of starting thread0 also failed, maybe it is related to the specific syntax requirement of threading?

I have a feeling that, nested using of `self` like this is probably not recommended. But in my real code, I do need threads declarations to be in the new process other than `main()`, so that those threads can share the same python logger of that process.

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep


class exe0(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.aaa = 111

        # working syntax for thread0
        t = threading.Thread(
            target=self.thread0,
            daemon=1,
        )
        t.start()

        try:
            # NOT working syntax
            t = threading.Thread(
                target=thread0,
                args=(self,),
                daemon=1,
            )
            t.start()
            sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def thread0(self):
        print(type(self))

    def run(self):

        # working syntax for thread1
        def thread1(self):
            print(type(self))
            print(self.aaa)

        t = threading.Thread(
            target=thread1,
            args=(self,),
            daemon=1,
        )
        t.start()
        sleep(1)

        try:
            # NOT working syntax
            t = threading.Thread(
                target=self.thread1,
                daemon=1,
            )
            t.start()
            sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    e = exe0()
    e.daemon = 1
    e.start()
    sleep(2)

# output:
'''
<class '__main__.exe0'>
name 'thread0' is not defined
<class '__mp_main__.exe0'>
111
'exe0' object has no attribute 'thread1'
'''
```

Comment: `self` was never magical to start with. You can call the first argument of a method anything you like -- the name `self` is just convention.

Comment: `thread1` is a local in `run`. It js not an attribute of `self`.

Comment: honestly I am not sure how to ask this, I can only feel that something is wrong.

Comment: yes, `self.thread1` causes the problem, but Why doesn't the syntax thread1(self) work the same way as thread0(self)? why thread0 is admitted to be a part of `self`, but not `thread1`. also, I am aware of the fact that `self` in `__init__(self)` is mutated and passed to `self` in a separate process that was started by `start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to understand that self is jussssst a variable name, what represent is another thing, to make your code work properly, you just have to pick another name to your variables, take a look:

> Important edit

You forget to target the method in the thread named `t4`

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep


class exe0(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.aaa = 111

        t1 = threading.Thread(
            target=self.thread0,
            daemon=1,
        )
        t1.start()

        try:
            t2 = threading.Thread(
                target=self.thread0, #here I removed the other parameter
                daemon=1,
            )
            t2.start()
            sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def thread0(self):
        print(type(self))


    def run(self):
        def thread1(s): #here you can see the name doesn't matter
            print(type(s)) #here you can see the name doesn't matter
            print(s.aaa)


        t3 = threading.Thread(
            target=thread1(self), 
            daemon=1,
        )
        t3.start()
        sleep(1)

        try:
            t4 = threading.Thread(
                target=thread1(self), #here there is no need of the parameter
                daemon=1,
            )
            t4.start()
            sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


multiprocessing.freeze_support()
e = exe0()
e.daemon = 1
e.start()
sleep(2)
```

And now you got the **6 outputs, for example:**

```
<class 'exe0'>
<class 'exe0'>
<class 'exe0'>
111
<class 'exe0'>
111
```

Comment: `self` is a just a variable, yes. it can be spelled anyways, yes. But, what does self point to? all the innards of this instance of the class right? So, is `s.thread1` ok now? or it is still error?

Comment: @eliu did you run the code I posted? because I did and worked fine. It should worl now. What is the question now? sorry I didnt  understand

Comment: I would assume you are using linux, because your code is not working on a win10 python 3.6 environment. There are exceptions regarding freeze_support(). there are exceptions regarding `TypeError: thread0() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`, anyways. the point is not how to make the codes work, my original code showed the working and none working syntax. The question was, why thread0 is part of the classs, but thread1 is not.

Comment: This is the output of my code,
 <class 'exe0'>
<class 'exe0'>
111
what do you mean with beeing part of? @eliu

Comment: there should be 6 print outs. if all 4 threads were successfully ran, then there should be 6 print statements. `self.property0` means `property0` is part of an instance that is referenced by `self`. `thread0` is part of the `self` that is the class of exe0 in main line's process. I expect `thread1` to be part of the `self` that is the running process forked away from the main line.

Comment: @eliu I count three prints, in your execution, you got 6? Because the code works as it should... if you expect 6 prints, you must do another think, I think I understand now...

Comment: thanks for staying with me on this. regarding prints count, thread0 runs twice and thread1 runs twice right? thread0 prints 1 message, thread1 prints 2 messages. 6 messages in total, unless some threads failed to start and didn't print any error messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149272/discussion-between-eliu-and-damian-lattenero).

Comment: @eliu I made an important update, I hope with that you can understand what happening